# Issue with kendo ui template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo ui tree with template http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/checkboxes.html

Kendo template doc http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Now my template is displaying checkbox to only leaf nodes

```
template:"#if(!item.hasChildren){# <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles#= item.id #' d_text='#=item.value#' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#'  value='true' />#}#"
```

I want to modify this template. I want this `name,d_text,parent_id` in `hidden` for all the nodes and check box is only in leaf node

Template for the hidden values

```
template: "<input type='hidden' name='checkedFiles#= item.id #' d_text='#=item.value#' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' />",
```

What changes do I have to do in template?

This is my jQuery code

```
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: false,
                    template:"#if(!item.hasChildren){# <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles#= item.id #' d_text='#=item.value#' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#'  value='true' />#}#"
                },
                dataSource: homogeneous,
                dataBound: ondata,
                dataTextField: "value"
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
 template:"# if(!item.hasChildren){# <input type='hidden' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#'/> <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='true' />#}else{# <input type='hidden' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' d_text='#=item.value#'/> #}#",
```